# Lost with the measure theoretic definition of a probability distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-integral

I am lost in the measure theoretic definition of a probability distribution. I am a computer science master student and although I have some mathematical background, I never had a formal training in measure theory.

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ be a mesurable space. Let $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a random variable on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})).$

The probability distribution of $X$ is the pushforward measure

(1) $\mathbb{P}_X (B) = \mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(B)) = \mathbb{P}(\{\omega\in \Omega \mid X(\omega) \in B\}), ~~~~ \forall B\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}).$

Can we say without any loss of generality that $\mathbb{P}_X(B) = \int_{x\in B} \mathbb{P}(dx)$ such that

(2) if $X$ is discrete then
$\mathbb{P}_X(B) = \sum_{x\in B} \mathbb{P}(X=x);$

(3) and if $X$ is continuous then
$\mathbb{P}_X(B) = \int_{x\in B} f(x) dx,$ where $f$ is a density function.

**Question 1**: Is it true?

**Question 2**: How can we go from (1) to (2)? What are the theorems to invoke?

**Question 3**: Can we justify (1) to (3) with the Radom-Nikodym theorem?

**Question 4**: I have trouble finding $\mathbb{P}_X(B) = \int_{x\in B} d\mathbb{P}(dx)$ written anywhere. Is it wrong? Or maybe trivial?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please define 'X is continuous'

Comment: Hello! I would say that $X$ is absolutely continuous.

Answer (score 2):

Note that we have

$$\mathbb{P}_X(A) = \mathbb{P}(X \in A) = \int_{\{X \in A\}} d\mathbb{P}$$

so (4) is definitely true.

If $X$ is absolutely continuous, then by definition there is a density function $g$ such that 
$$\mathbb{P}_X(A) = \int_A g d \lambda$$

You don't need Radon-Nikodym. It's the definition.

For (2),

$$\mathbb{P}_X(B) = \mathbb{P}_X\left(\bigcup_{x \in B} \{x\}\right) = \sum_{x \in B} \mathbb{P}_X(\{x\}) = \sum_{x \in B} \mathbb{P}(X = x)$$

note that the union becomes a sum because $X$ is discrete and we can view this as a countable sum (to be really formal, we should sum over all elements with non-zero probability).

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! Is $d\mathbb{P}$ should be prefered over $\mathbb{P}(dx)$? I think I understand the meaning of $\mathbb{P}(dx),$ but not really $d\mathbb{P}.$

Comment: We have $\int_A Z d \mathbb{P}  := \int_A Z(\omega) \mathbb{P}(d\omega)$ if $Z$ is a random variable. Compare with $\int_a^b f:= \int_a^b f(x) dx$ for Riemann-integrals.

Comment: Thank you again! So we can say that $\mathbb{P}_X (A) = \int_{\{X\in A\}} d\mathbb{P}$ is a general form from which we can get the probability distribution of discrete, continuous and mixed random variable?

Comment: Basically yes. That's what happens.